# NVIDIA 960m: Game Not playing on discrete card

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, optimus

I am currently trying to play Final Fantasy 11 on my I7 /16GB RAM / 2GB NVIDIA 960m laptop.  This game is quite old and it's Recommended settings are a pentium 2 and 128MB PCI graphics card.  I think this machine is a bit over qualified.

Despite this, the game sometimes struggles to keep even 10 FPS and is borderline un-playable.  I tracked this down and found out through multiple tools that the game is running on the Intel Integrated (HD5600) graphics card and not the NVIDIA 960m discrete card.  From all reports, this integrated card does not support DirectX 8.1

I have tried going to the NVIDIA control panel and setting POL.exe (game executeable) to use the discrete card.  I have also tried setting the the global setting to use the discrete card.  The game still runs on the integrated card.

Both graphics card drivers have been kept fully up to date.  I contacted NVIDIA support line for help, which was a horrible experience. I had to 10-20 minute waits between each response because he had to help multiple people at once....  They first told me to do what I told them I had already done (Control panel above).  They then had me re-install the same graphics driver TWICE (once with a "Clean Install"). Neither of this helped.  They then told me to use a third party driver uninstaller because their driver uninstaller doesn't always get rid of everything that their driver installs...Bad joke? Nope they were serious.

I looked into their utility and used it to uninstall the NVIDIA drivers and reinstall the latest driver clean again.  Repeated the above control panel and the game still runs on the integrated graphics card.

I then downloaded both the stock drivers for the integrated and nvidia chip from MSI, uninstalled everything with the utility (in safe mode) and installed those drivers.  Rebooted and repeated the control panel stuff again... game still runs on the integrated card.

I have also tried un-installing and/or disabling the integrated card through the device manager, which just lead to me not having any external displays and the game crashing on launch.  There are no options in the UEFI related to disabling the integrated card.

99.9% of the time I do not have to worry about running out of battery.  Is there something I can disable or custom driver I can install that will resolve this issue and let me enjoy this game?

---

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 11/24/2016, 00:21:45
         Machine name: MSI
           Machine Id: 
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393) (14393.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
         System Model: GE62 2QD
                 BIOS: E16J2IMS.113
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5700HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
               Memory: 16384MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 16296MB RAM
            Page File: 4197MB used, 14529MB available
          Windows Dir: 
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
       DxDiag Version: 10.00.14393.0000 64bit Unicode
```

---

### Display Devices

```
      Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5600
   Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
      Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
       DAC type: Internal
    Device Type: Full Device
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1612&SUBSYS_11381462&REV_0A
  Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
```

Device Problem Code: No Problem
Driver Problem Code: Unknown
     Display Memory: 8275 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 128 MB
      Shared Memory: 8147 MB

```
      Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M    
   Manufacturer: NVIDIA
      Chip type: GeForce GTX 960M
       DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
    Device Type: Render-Only Device
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B&SUBSYS_11381462&REV_A2
  Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
```

Device Problem Code: No Problem
Driver Problem Code: Unknown
     Display Memory: 10143 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 1995 MB
      Shared Memory: 8147 MB

Comment: I don't know the details of FF11 but are you sure that `POL.exe` is the actual executable for the game? Does the task manager show appropriate RAM usage for it?

Comment: @seth I traced it back through the Task manager, while the game was the only thing running and using 30% CPU, to be sure.  This game itself does not have an exe, but is run as sort of a plugin to POL (among other games)

Comment: I put the full path to the exe in the control panel, and it brought me to the existing entry.  So I know I have the right exe.